# Can I save an 'Object' in a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I want to save an object (of any type) into a field in a database in SQL Server 2005. Is it possible? Do I have to convert the object into something, like a byte array for example and cast it back when retrieving it?

Comment: You could also serialize out to XML which would be easier to inspect inside the db than binary data

Comment: It's not a great DB design.  Will you need to query the attributes of the object at any point?  e.g. get all objects where object.Foo = 1.

Comment: No i don't need to know or query the contents of the tables stored

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `VARBINARY(MAX)` field type in SQL Server, if you like. You can store any type of object in there, up to 2 GB in size.

To access it, you can use ADO.NET - something like this:

```
object yourMysteryObject = (whatever you like it to be);

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memStream);

sw.Write(yourMysteryObject);

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TableName(VarBinaryColumn) VALUES (@VarBinary)", sqlConnection);

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@VarBinary", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);

sqlCmd.Parameters["@VarBinary"].Value = memStream.GetBuffer();

sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Marc

Comment: but how can i transfer an object into a VARBINARY type?

Comment: but this is an image read from a file. What if I have a class or an object created during runtime. Nothing to do with files.

Comment: any type of object can be written to a MemoryStream and thus assigned to the value of the SqlParameter which will then write it down into the database.

Comment: how can i write an object to a memory stream? without dealing with the hard disk? can u give me an example plz?

Comment: Look at my code - create a MemoryStream and a StreamWriter and write your object to this MemoryStream -- that's all done in memory, no disk

Comment: LOL @ yourMysteryObject :D thx dude :)
and when retrieving it back, normal type casting right?

Comment: Well, if you want it back, you'll have to know what you get back! SQL Server is just going to send you any number of bytes - it's YOU who has to know what it is and how to convert the stream of bytes into an object again.

Comment: oh what do you mean. I know that it is, I mean its type. Can't I just say like:

DataTable dt;
while(reader.Read())
{
    dt = (DataTable)reader[2];
}

Comment: Huh? If you pass sw.Write() a generic Object, it just calls that Object's ToString method! That doesn't serialize it!

Answer (score 32):

I would use [JSON](http://www.json.org/) to convert the object to a string, and store it in a VARCHAR or TEXT field. Not only the data is stored in a human-readable format, but it's also also readable from different languages, since pretty much every mainstream language has a JSON parser available.

The link I posted has links to several libraries in many languages (including C#), I have used [this one](https://atifaziz.github.io/projects/jayrock/) a couple times in the past.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example if you are using Entity Framework (EF):

```
using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    // The object that you want to serialize. In this case it is just an empty instance
    YourObject objectToSerialize = new YourObject();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);

        // EF model. In one of its properties you store the serialized object
        YourModel modelObject = new YourModel();

        // In your model 'SerializedObject' should be of type byte[]. In the database it should be of type varbinary(MAX)
        modelObject.SerializedObject = stream.ToArray(); 
        db.YourModel.Add(modelObject);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And this is how to de-serialize the object:

```
// De-serialize
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(serializedObject);
YourObject deserializedYourObject = (YourObject)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: How do you cast it back to the object we just saved... knowing what the original object was obviously.

Comment: @ppumpkin. I have updated my answer with information how to de-serialize the object. Happy coding :)

Comment: The class being serialized must be marked with the Serializable attribute.

Answer (score 13):

As others have said, serialization may be the key here (assuming you don't want to use ORM to store the properties as columns in a table, which seems much more direct).

Some caveats though; a database is:

- long term storage
- not related to your .NET code

As such, you do **not** want to use any serialization technique that is platform-specific or version-specific. You will often see people mention `BinaryFormatter` for persistance, but this falls into both of the above traps. You would be scuppered if you ever changed platform, or even if you just [change some properties](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html).

You need an implementation-independent approach; the simplest (which also retains the ability to be human readable) is xml or json, perhaps via `XmlSerializer` or Json.NET (stored in a `[n]varchar(max)`). If you don't care about human readable, "protocol buffers" (fast/binary) would do well (stored in a `varbinary(max)`), and is [available for most platforms](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) (including C#/.NET/etc).

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to serialize your object.
You can look here at examples:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bipinjoshi/serializingObjectsinCS11102005234746PM/serializingObjectsinCS.aspx

Comment: But I don't want to save it on hard disk. I just want to put it in a databse.

Comment: BinaryFormatter is a **very bad choice** for long term storage.